# if 'this case' and 'that case' do 'something' else do 'other something'

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, onclick

I'm trying to create an onClick function which only works below resolution of 768px. The function works on other resolutions such as 992px and above, but for some reason the function still works on resolution 768px itself.

following is my code:

```js
$(document).on('click','.active-tab', function(e){
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
      $(this).siblings().slideUp("fast");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $(this).parent().find('li').slideDown("fast");
    }
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.active-tabs {
  ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style: none;
    li {
      display: none;
    }
    li:first-child {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li class="active-tab"><a href="">ALL</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TAB ONE</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TAB TWO</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TAB THREE</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TAB FOUR</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

[for when resolution is above 768](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2URZM.jpg)

[for when resolution is below 768](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGGm7.jpg)

[the onClick function whenever below 768](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7wGQ.jpg)

Is it the syntax where I am mistaken? or perhaps I'm forgetting something?
Appreciate the help guys, thanks.

Comment: Please include all relevant code

Comment: So if I understand correct, you want click to do something if resolution is either `< 768` or is `>= 992`. Correct?

Comment: I want the click to do something if the resolution is below 768 only. above 768, do nothing.

Comment: @GervinSeanMiranda  Your function works perfectly.  I went ahead and tested it by printing out the current `$(window).width()` and resized my window to the correct size and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I added the HTML if it helps, idk what other codes you need

Comment: @nfnneil so my problem could be on the CSS? because the click function still executes whenever im on resolution of 768

Comment: @GervinSeanMiranda Your `a` tag is making the action. Do `$('.tabs a').on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); })`

Comment: @Rajesh I tried specifying it specifically to the anchor tag, now the function wont work even below 768.

Comment: okay i added CSS now i hope it helps you guys to diagnose my problem here :(

Comment: @GervinSeanMiranda You will need 2 events. Above one will block all anchor click. Second one will take care of UI behavior.

Comment: @GervinSeanMiranda can you also update what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Rajesh I've uploaded a few screenshots to give you an idea on what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem in your post seems to unfounded, but I did notice that there were some logic errors that would cause the first click not to work properly.  If you need a reference to prove your check is working, [click here](http://neil.computer/stack/gervin.html) (becuase you can't resize a SO snippet).

## A different way of achieving a similar effect

I'd first recommend fixing your anchor tag.  You could add `javascript:void(0)` into it or simply put `#`.

```
<li class="active-tab"><a href="javascript:void(0);">ALL</a></li>
```

## If you are only using this code to toggle visibility

However, there is one way to further simplify your code.  You can use `toggle` to get around one of your if structures:

```
$(document).on('click','.active-tab', function(e){
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $(this).siblings().toggle("fast");
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

## If you need more options

Here's a version of your code that uses `toggleClass`.

```
if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
  $(this).siblings().slideUp("fast");
} else {
  $(this).siblings().slideDown("fast");
}
$(this).toggleClass('active');
```

Comment: I gave your solutions a try,
I can't use the first solution because I need to give a class so that I can make changes using CSS.
The second solution is better because i still can give class.
But both solutions is still executing the click function at the resolution of 768

Comment: @GervinSeanMiranda Your comment seems to be cut off.

Comment: @GervinSeanMiranda Your code works fine as it.  Refer to:  http://neil.computer/stack/gervin.html  .  Just resize the window.  I'm not sure how you're setting the width of the window but that might be flawed.  If you're setting the outside width of the window, that will be less than you're JavaScript window.

Comment: I'm resizing through Google Chrome's inspect element feature. But yes, I understand what you're trying to say, because when I go to a resolution of 788, the click function no longer executes.

Comment: I did it through device toolbar and it works fine...  I'm 90% your method of resizing is incorrect and the code is correct as there is no real way to fix `<` symbol.  And `window` would be the farthest out you can go.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I'm using as well.. not sure why my screen size isn't 768 even-though it says 768. but anyhow, thanks for the help!

Comment: @GervinSeanMiranda It's weird, some resolutions I set don't have the correct window.width.  That could be what is happening.  But unless someone is inspect, you shouldn't encounter a problem.  If you manually resize the whole window, it works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Please use this code

HTML

```
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active-tab" href="">ALL</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TAB ONE</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TAB TWO</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TAB THREE</a></li>
   <li><a href="">TAB FOUR</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
    .tabs li{
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:top;
    }
    .tabs li a.active-tab{
        color:red;
    }   

    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .tabs li{
            display:block;
        }
        .tabs li:not(:first-child){
            display:none;
        }
    }
```

jQuery

```
$('.tabs').on('click','a', function(e){
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {    
    $(this).parent('li').siblings().slideToggle("fast");
  } else {      
    $('.tabs a').removeClass('active-tab');
    $(this).addClass('active-tab');
  } 
  e.preventDefault();
});


$(window).on('load resize', function () {
    $('.tabs li').removeAttr('style');      
});
```

Comment: Answers with code and no explanation make it difficult for future readers to learn.